# please how can I post String in array Object JSON in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

please How can I post this JSON

```
 {
  "name": "Premium Quality",
  "type": "simple",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

to android with retrofit

i have successfully sent a string, but this array i cannot
Like sending a image

My Code

API

```
    {
public interface interfaceAPI

    @POST("wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_006dd346d4c87128f924a93983e7d51be528d1&consumer_secret=cs_d4b421317da42bd58a3f3db6a4cc4644d20a78e3")
    Call<Product> PRODUCT_CALL_POST(@Body HashMap<Object, Object> map);



}
```

CLASS POST

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.Model.Product;
import com.example.myapplication.Model.images;
import com.example.myapplication.callAPI.interfaceAPI;
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityPostBinding;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class post extends AppCompatActivity {


    ActivityPostBinding binding;
    private final static int intent_get_img = 1;


    String name= "name";
    String regular_price= "regular_price";
    String src = "src";
    //String images = "images";
    images images;
    Uri uriimg;


    interfaceAPI interfaceAPI ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = ActivityPostBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());





        binding.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent getimg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                getimg.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(getimg, intent_get_img);

            }
        });



        binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                postproduct();

            }
        });






    }

    private void postproduct()
    {
        try {
        JSONArray imagesA = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject images =new JSONObject();


            images.put("src", uriimg.toString());

            imagesA.put(images);


            HashMap<Object, Object> post_map =new HashMap<>();
            post_map.put("name",binding.productName.getText().toString());
            post_map.put("regular_price",binding.price.getText().toString());
            //  images =new images(uriimg.toString());

            post_map.put("images",new Gson().toJson(imagesA));


            //method
            getPostCall(post_map);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }







    }

    private void getPostCall(HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap)
    {



        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://carddoom.com/shop/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        interfaceAPI = retrofit.create(com.example.myapplication.callAPI.interfaceAPI.class);

        Call<Product> productCall= interfaceAPI.PRODUCT_CALL_POST(hashMap );

        productCall.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(post.this, "Successfully post Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(post.this, "API Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(post.this, "API Erorr: "+ t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                binding.button.setText(t.getMessage());
                Log.getStackTraceString(t);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode== intent_get_img && data!= null && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            uriimg = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(uriimg).into(binding.imageView);

        }


    }

}
```

I've tried using JSONObject, but it doesn't work

HashMap has partially solved the problem.

I hope to find your help

Any help would be appreciated :)
have good days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a tired days, I have solved myproblem :)

```
    HashMap<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put( name ,"Premium Quality222" );
    map.put( regular_price ,"21.99" );
      images = new images("http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg");
      ArrayList<images> imagesArrayList = new ArrayList<com.example.myapplication.Model.images>();
      imagesArrayList.add(images);
    map.put(imagesString , imagesArrayList);
      ArrayList<categories> categoriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
      categories = new categories(111);
      categoriesArrayList.add(categories);
    map.put(categoriesString, categoriesArrayList);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://carddoom.com/shop/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    interfaceAPI = retrofit.create(com.example.myapplication.callAPI.interfaceAPI.class);

    Call<Product2> productCall= interfaceAPI.PRODUCT_CALL_POST(map);
```